# what type of data am i comparing?

Tags: c, stack, compare

I have to check if the top card of s1 and s2. s1 is a stack of cards and so is s2. The stack_top function i already have, is the following:

```
/* Retrive data from the top of the stack */
node_data stack_top(stack *s){
  if(!stack_empty(s)){      /* If the stack is not empty */
    return (s->top->data);  /* Return the data */
  }
  else{             /* Otherwise there is an error */
    cardlist_error("stack_top called on empty stack");
  }
}
```

I had

```
while (strcmp (stack_top(s1), stack_top(s2)) ==0 )
//then do the following..
```

but i got an `segmentation fault`, how should i compare them 2?

Comment: You really should return something from your function in the case of the stack being empty. If your function says it is going to return something you should make it return something **whatever** happens

Comment: You need to compare the contents of the `node_data` that is being returned by `stack_top`. (You didn't include the definition of `node_data`, so it's hard to say exactly what you need to compare; all you showed was that `stack_top` returns `s->top->data`, with no indication of what `data` is other than a `node_data`.) What determines whether or not they're equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether two `stack` pointers both point to the same instance, just check that their addresses match `s1 == s2`.

If you want to check that two `stack` pointers both hold identical data and the struct only has non-pointer members, you can check `memcmp(s1, s2, sizeof(*s1)) == 0`.

If you want to check that two `stack` pointers both hold identical data and the struct has pointers (e.g. strings), you may need to write a function which compares two instances by comparing each of their members in turn.